# Find matching sequences that have exactly one deviation

Tags: c#, regex, t-sql

I'm trying to implement a feature which takes a sequence of digits (U.S. Social Security Numbers) as an argument and returns a collection of SSNs which match the input except for exactly one deviation.

So, the input 123456789 would return:

- 123**3**56789
- 1**9**3456789
- 12345**0**789

But would not return 123**54**6789, etc.

I have a system in ASP.NET which does pattern matches on inputs with wildcards, like 123**6789. So I could adapt that, using a loop, to this. But if there was a single regex for this, I would just implement it in SQL and be done with it.

So, is there a regex that will do this without having to call it in a for loop?

Comment: No, there's no regex. You want the [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)

Comment: Or [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: To be clear, I don't want the degree of the deviation of one character, or the number of deviations, I just want all results that do deviate by exactly one position of the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not specialist in regular expressions but I think that you can use simple regular expression to check absolute value of subtraction between testing value and your input value. Acceptable result should be exactly 1 digit and 0 or more trailing zeroes. For your example values:

```
Testing value    Input value    ABS(Subtraction)
--------------+--------------+------------------
123356789        123456789      100000
193456789        123456789      70000000
123450789        123456789      6000
123456786        123456789      3
```

Comment: SELECT [column]
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE LEN(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),ABS(@input - [column])),'0','')) = 1

Comment: @Bozman, thank you for your comment - this is also my preffered solution, but I mentioned only regexp as it was asked about in the question. Good point, thanx.